# How do use Magento CLI to reindex

Tags: php, magento

I have encounterd an error message in Magento It states:

> One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is
>   running.

The virtual host is  C:\site\mysite.com\magento

I tried using the CLI to get `magento indexer:reindex`

Answer (score 0):

Using CLI, navigate to your magento installation root and reindex..

```
php magento indexer:reindex
```

or

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Search a bit, and you should see a lot of resources online as this is a common issue.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html